# ckeditor 4, versioning

Tags: plugins, load, ckeditor, version

I would like to know if it is possible give the possibility to load a previous version of the current content through a button in the toolbar. 
The different versions of content are stored in a database. 
The ideal behavior would be that clicking on the button in the toolbar, a popup dialog opens with a list of previous versions of the content. On click, the selected content is loaded into the editor.

I'm using php and mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement a custom plugin that by ajax get the versions:

[Creating a CKEditor Plugin with a Custom Dialog Window](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/SimpleLink_Plugin_Part_1)

[CKEDITOR Plugin SDK](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_intro)